Are Unique Options FX and Unique Options a scam?
I invested in Bitcoin through Unique Options FX uniqueoptionsfx.com I paid fee after fee after more fees. Unique Options FX was closed and Unique-Options has been opened. Now unique-options.com website is down.
Is there a way that I can recover my funds?

Sounds like scam to me, so probably not.

Websearch finds a fair number of Unique Whatever, variously reported as ponzi scheme or other scam. See, for example, https://mena.news/unique-finance-scam/

Remember that anyone who asks you to pay fees rather than offering to deduct the money from your account is almost certainly a scammer. And that anyone guaranteeing exceptional results definitely is.

If the enforcement agencies are able to shut down a scammer, they may be able to recover some of the money. So it's worth reporting this to the regulatory agencies. But I would assume the money is gone.

There was a previous post about this, closed because it was worded as a statement rather than a question and the author didn't want to bother restructuring is as a self-answered question.
Quoting it for those who don't have access:

Unique Options fx website claims a lot of things, honest, trustworthy,
transparent, and guaranteed results just to name a few. They claimed I
would receive my disbursement after paying a fee. However they add fee
after fee after more fees. They add fees like non-continuing fees,
verification fees, processing fees, COT fees, require to purchase a
2-year FX CERTIFICATE at $6,200. Once all of the fees were paid, they
claimed they have poor service and having connection issues. I highly
recommend no one does business with them.
 edited May 1 at 2:57
 asked Apr 17 at 5:06
 Charles Rennaker


Note that COT is an absolute red flag; no such fee exists except in scams.

@TripeHound: Users may be able to see it if they have 10k+ reputation (I don't, and you don't either...)

Quoted, tnx for reminding me.
